# Estimate class proportions of a feature, central limit theorem

Tags: dataset, pandas, parameter-estimation, bootstraping

haven't been feeling smart lately and this is probably the most trivial question ever but I really need to know. I'm trying to point estimate some population parameters. I sampled from 1000 randomly generated bootstrapped samples of 130000 observations and saved the frequency & percentile of each class of a categorical feature.

If I were take an average of the percentile or frequency, would that be a good way to estimate a proportion for the classes of a feature?  I know this issue seems easy.... but please help me.

Comment: I don’t see how the central limit theorem is involved.

Comment: Well, I did perform bootstrapping and record the standard deviation 1000 times. The distribution of the data-set of STDs look normal so I thought I take the average to approximate the STD.